# Problems baking a texture

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, sculpting, baking

### **Hello community. I need help!**

*Context:*

This is my first attempt in sculpting and also first time baking a map.

I had this mid poly model - I made it a long time ago and was intending to do some studies with it - then I made some sculpt on it, it got heavy to handle due the number of polygons, so I found this work flow of high to low poly using baking textures, but I jumped the step of re-topology thinking that my first model without sculpted details should work as a re-topology mesh, might be one of the reasons of my poor results, or not, I don't know. Another problems is my UV MAP and seams (Mainly in the face), there is a time since my days studying 3D and I did not used to do UV mapping frequently, so I am missing something. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advanced

[image: My two models]

*My two models*

[image: The mid poly seams]

*The mid poly seams, the seam in the middle of the calf it was for trying to fix the texture baked*

[image: Mid poly UV - Area Stretching]

*Mid poly UV - Area Stretching*

[image: Mid poly UV - Angle Stretching]

*Mid poly UV - Angle Stretching*

[image: Baked resulted issues]

*Baked resulted issues*

[image: Baked resulted issues]

*Baked resulted issues*

[image: Baked Map]

*Baked Map*

[image: Bake settings]

*Bake settings*

Comment: I am not sure what you are wanting. Are you wanting to bump map the High poly model onto the low poly model? If so you may need the models to be just a little more alike to minimize the stretching. Bump mapping is usually for finer details like scales, rivets, and wrinkles.